# Video from URL working on Android 4 but not on Android 9

Tags: android

This code works on Android 4.4.2 but does not work on the phone with Android 9:

```
String url="http://...LINK...mp4";
MediaController controller = new MediaController(context);
controller.setMediaPlayer(holder.video);
Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
holder.video.setVideoURI(videoUri);
holder.video.requestFocus();
holder.video.start();
```

On Android 9 I receive the error (no error on Android 4.4.2):

```
Couldn't open http://...LINK...mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://...LINK...mp4
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Switch to an `https` URL.

Comment: Perfect!!! Thank you :-) Please write it as an answer I will mark as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 9.0 [blocks cleartext (`http`) traffic by default](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#framework-security-changes).

The preferred solution is to not use `http` URLs, but instead use `https`.

You can, through network security configuration, tell Android to allow cleartext traffic for your app, but this is less secure.

Comment: Please tell me just in case how can I modify my network security configuration so that it allows http?

Comment: I understand, I will try to use https

Comment: Can you allow clearText for all URLs or do you have to specify each URL?

Comment: @KrisB: You can specify by domain, and you can include subdomains (so allowing `foo.com` would also allow `www.foo.com` and `bar.foo.com`). You *can* do a blanket allow rule (`<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">`), but I would not be surprised if that starts running afoul of Play Store rules sometime in the future.

Comment: I actually have `<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">` in my Network Security Configuration file and it's still blocking non-HTTP sites.  I'm going to be screwed because I use a third-party API to return RSS feeds to my app and not all of them use HTTPS.

Comment: Nevermind, I had the networkSecurityConfig entry in the wrong place.  It's allowing HTTP URLs now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one line code in the manifest file. Its working for me.

```
 <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".EvaBotView"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
    </application>
```

Inside application tag we can use **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"** which can resolve this issue.